# React table Gives empty table in build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, react-router, react-table

This is a very strange issue but I was using react-table 7.0.0.rc16 and I recently upgraded to react-table 7.0.1 the problem is my data works in dev mode but as soon I create a react build it wont render anything I would like to know why and I am attaching my package.json for the same.
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-paper-hmzxh?file=/src/App.js)

[Demo](https://csb-hmzxh-ap5fj53r4.vercel.app/)

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "homepage": "http://www.test.com",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.39",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "echarts": "4.2.1",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.15-beta.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "formik-material-ui": "^0.0.22",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.5",
    "i18next": "^17.0.18",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.0.0",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.0",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-d3-tree": "^1.16.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-i18next": "^10.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.0.3",
    "react-table": "7.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "watch": "react-scripts start --watch",
    "build": "CI=false react-scripts --expose-gc --max-old-space-size=4096 build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**Package-lock.json** is also attached as a [file](https://easyupload.io/ponybc)

image of table

[image: image of table when doing prod build]

I am using node v10.23.1 and npm 6.14.10.

Comment: Is their any conflict with the packages?

Comment: did you use any api to import data from backend?

Comment: no the data is generated on the UI itself

Comment: check the sandbox attached

Comment: the sandbox url is the same as the demo

Comment: i have updated it. The package.json is quite large for sandbox but it renders fine as soon as you deploy it we get empty tables in production build. Please check it.

Comment: please check https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-paper-hmzxh?file=/package.json

Comment: @MohamedRamrami please check the updates in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with react-table v7.0.1, upgrading to v7.0.2 fixes the problem.

It's a minification bug. Here is the exact [commit](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/commit/9a8dc0fedae22bb7e61c60204fc50d32de9bc3b5) that fixed the problem.

From the Changelog :

> ### 7.0.2
>
> - Fixed an issue where the internal flexRenderer would not work correctly in production due to the strangest friggin' minification bug
>   I've ever encountered. ‍♂️

Comment: So I have tried it with my sandbox it works fine but previously I was using latest version and it created this problem I will update the project and let you know